# How to integrate Cocoa code in Qt

Tags: cocoa, qt

Like the title says, how do I add my `.h` and `.m` files to Qt Creator?

Comment: add them as headers and sources in .pro file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add OBJECTIVE_SOURCES in your Qt Creator project ".pro" file like

```
OBJECTIVE_SOURCES += \
mac/cocoainitializer.mm
```

and headers in the usual way like

```
HEADERS += \
mac/cocoainitializer.h
```